# caching UIView objects as a way to improve performance

Tags: iphone, performance, ios, view

Obviously Apple does this with UITableViewCells.  I am curious if anyone has tried it with other UIView subclasses.  And if so, what was your experience?

Answer (score 2):

HJCache caches and shares UIImage objects in order to make tables with downloaded images scroll smoothly, even on first generation iPhones. Note, it shares UIImage, not UIImageView.

http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/